# How can i add space between rows and in between each image button?

Tags: android, android-layout

```
<TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/tableLayout"
            android:layout_width="318dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:gravity="center_vertical" 
           >

        <TableRow

        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        > 

            <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/Button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/tile_cat"
            android:onClick="buttonClickHandler2"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:tag="1" 
            android:layout_marginLeft="2sp"/>

         <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/Button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/tile_dog"
        android:onClick="buttonClickHandler2"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:tag="2" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/tile_cow"
            android:onClick="buttonClickHandler2"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:tag="3"
             />
         </TableRow>

         <TableRow 
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        >
        <ImageButton 
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/tile_lion"
            android:onClick="buttonClickHandler2"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:tag="4"

            />

        <ImageButton 
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/tile_sheep"
            android:onClick="buttonClickHandler2"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:tag="5"
            />
        <ImageButton 
            android:id="@+id/button6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/tile_elephant"
            android:onClick="buttonClickHandler2"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:tag="6"
            />
        </TableRow>
```

**I got this xml i want to add space between each button with in same row and between rows so it looks good , Kindly guid me that can it be done with in xml or i have to use some java code because while searching i got this idea which isn't working**

```
TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);  
        TableLayout.LayoutParams tableParams=
          new TableLayout.LayoutParams
          (TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

tableParams.setMargins(8, 8, 8, 8);

        tr.setLayoutParams(tableParams);
```

**Please help just stuck :/**

Answer (score 0):

I think this post is over an year old. Did you tried to change the Margin fields in the property page of each rows that is displayed in the graphical layout of the xml file.

Regards
Ansif